# How can we do progressive streaming from local cache in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-streaming, progressive

All,

I have an interesting problem:

I need a mechanism to progressively stream video content stored in my local cache.

The content stored in the local cache will be downloading in the background. So as and when the download content is available the MPMoviePlayer should be notified that more content is available and keep playing.

--Srihari